# Is it possible to pass a query as parameter in BIRT report?

Tags: sql, birt

I want to ask the user to input a query then the BIRT will generate a report based on user's query.

So far, what I do is pass the parameter to `this.queryText` but I can't think of a way on how will BIRT display the results.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any other option aside from this.

First. (I use java btw) My program accepts and execute the query. Then using the `ResultSetMetaData`, I get the column names. (to be use as reference to my data source)

Then. I passed the full query and the list of columns to the method `buildReport()` (Please refer to  [How to Build Dynamic Table (BIRT)](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Java_-_Build_Dynamic_Table_(BIRT)) sample code)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following below steps :-

1. Create **report parameters** if required, which can be passed by user.
2. In SQL dataset **beforeOpen()** event build and assign dynamic query:-
      example- *this.queryText = "Select * from " + params["parmtable"].value;*

If you have any other requirement, could you please elaborate it. I will surely try to help you with a sample rptdesign file.

Comment: Appreciated sir. this is the scenario.  the user can input either `SELECT COL1,COL2 FROM TABLE1` or ` SELECT COL1,COL2,COL3 FROM TABLE2`  etc now I want to generate a report based on the results of these queries. Where in the column of the report must correspond also on the number of selected columns.

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly possible.

However, with a little help from outside (e.g. getting the *description* of the cursor from the DB, it is possible to generate (and save, if you like) and finally run an rptdesign file by calling the DE API from Javascript. I've done this, but it is very cumbersome. Furthermore, what if the user wants to supply parameters?

From a security point of view, the whole approach is not recommended.

IMHO BIRT is not the right tool for this, because this task requires more low level programming. If you are free to choose, I'd recommend Python with the [ReportLab](https://www.reportlab.com/opensource/) toolkit (a library to generate PDF) together with cx_Oracle (depending on your DB) or Java with iText and JDBC.